# Как центрировать <li> относительно границ <ul>?

Tags: html, css

Как можно центрировать  элементы списка `<li>` относительно границ списка `<ul>`?

```css
ul {
  border: dashed blue 2px;
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  border: dashed green 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Вам надо просто чтобы синяя и зелёная границы совпадали?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov чтобы блок с зелеными границами был по центру блока с синими границами. Хотя растянуть границы li на всю ширину ul тоже вариант. Было бы здорово узнать оба варианта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Rumata Может так?

```css
ul {
  border: dashed blue 2px;
  list-style-position: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  border: dashed green 2px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает! Только нужно ли задавать margin и padding для <li>, если он уже задан для <ul>? 

И второй вопрос: теоретически - возможно ли именно центрировать <li>  относительно <ul>, не растягивая на его ширину?

Comment: @Rumata
"нужно ли задавать margin и padding для <li>" - теоритически нет ))
"возможно ли именно центрировать <li> относительно <ul>" - да, если например для UL  поставить 
width:100%; 
 а  LI
 width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;  
то <li> всегда будет в центе родителя